# Mojo WP Plugin issue - cli-init.php error

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a WP website and now locked out with the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')' in [my site]/wp-content/plugins/mojo-marketplace-wp-plugin/inc/cli-init.php on line 25. I have traced this back to my code. Here is what lines 20-35:

```
protected $commands = array(
    array(
        'cmd'       => 'branding',
        'class'     => 'EIG_WP_CLI_Branding',
        'shortdesc' => 'Control hosting branding and UX.',
        'longdesc'  => 'Control the admin interface, default modules and UX for an Endurance hosting brand.' .
                       PHP_EOL . 'Subcommands: update, remove',
    ),
    array(
        'cmd'       => 'cache',
        'class'     => 'EIG_WP_CLI_Cache',
        'shortdesc' => 'Control all forms of caching.',
        'longdesc'  => 'Control how browser cache, page cache and browser caching are configured.' .
                       PHP_EOL . 'Cache Types: browser, page, object (not functional yet)' .
                       PHP_EOL . 'Subcommands: add, update, status',
    ),
```

I am not seeing any issues although I am not super familiar with the code. Any thoughts on what can be going on? I am  currently configured to use PHP Edge (7.1) Thanks in advance!

Comment: What server environment are you running (Linux/WIndows)?

Comment: The constant **PHP_EOL** is not defined on your system for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am running windows which I assume using "WIN" is correct. I have done some searching around and I never see "PHP_EOL" being referenced in the "wp-config.php" file so I am wondering what is causing me to have the need to do this. Either way, I have added that code to the wp-config.php file without much luck.

Comment: Is this error occuring on your admin dashboard or the front end of the site, or both?

Comment: Update: this was being caused by the mojo-marketplace.php file which I don't have a use for so I disabled that and it cleared up my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found 2 of my sites with this same issue this morning.  Going into the PHP settings for the hosts, it was parsing with php 5.4.  highest I could set it to is 7.1, but that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The constant PHP_EOL is not defined on your system for some reason.

Add the following to your wp-config.php file:

```
if(!defined("PHP_EOL")) {
    define("PHP_EOL", strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) == "WIN") ? "\r\n" : "\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the **/mojo-marketplace-wp-plugin/** directory worked for me a few minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it was not able to parse the string inside the array.

I changed the syntax to remove the concatenation with PHP_EOL and I was able to fix it without changing the PHP version or deleting the plugin:

```
    /**
     * Main variable containing all WP-CLI commands and callbacks.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = array(
        array(
            'cmd'       => 'branding',
            'class'     => 'EIG_WP_CLI_Branding',
            'shortdesc' => 'Control hosting branding and UX.',
            'longdesc'  => 'Control the admin interface, default modules and UX for an Endurance hosting brand.\n
            Subcommands: update, remove',
        ),
        array(
            'cmd'       => 'cache',
            'class'     => 'EIG_WP_CLI_Cache',
            'shortdesc' => 'Control all forms of caching.',
            'longdesc'  => 'Control how browser cache, page cache and browser caching are configured.\n
            Cache Types: browser, page, object (not functional yet)\n
            Subcommands: add, update, status',
        ),
        array(
            'cmd'       => 'digest',
            'class'     => 'EIG_WP_CLI_Digest',
            'shortdesc' => 'Analyze WordPress for this site.',
            'longdesc'  => 'Analyze WordPress content, configuration and server environment.\n
                           Associative Args: --full --noprompt',
        ),
        array(
            'cmd'       => 'secrets',
            'class'     => 'EIG_WP_CLI_Secrets',
            'shortdesc' => 'Control the WordPress Salts.',
            'longdesc'  => 'Read and update WordPress salts in the wp-config.php file.\n
                           Subcommands: update, age, list',
        ),
        array(
            'cmd'       => 'remove_orphan_post_meta',
            'class'     => 'EIG_WP_CLI_Remove_Orphan_Post_Meta',
            'shortdesc' => 'Legacy cmd for removing orphan meta.',
            'longdesc'  => 'Legacy WP-CLI command used for checking for orphaned postmeta.',
        ),
        array(
            'cmd'       => 'sso',
            'class'     => 'EIG_WP_CLI_SSO',
            'shortdesc' => 'Single sign-on from hosting platform.',
            'longdesc'  => 'Handle single sign-on from Endurance hosting platforms and get magic link.\n
                           Associative Args: --username --role --email --id --min=MINUTES_UNTIL_EXPIRE --url-only',
        ),
        array(
            'cmd'       => 'staging',
            'class'     => 'EIG_WP_CLI_Staging',
            'shortdesc' => 'CRUD operations for EIG staging.',
            'longdesc'  => 'Internal commands to handle staging environment.\n
                                         Subcommands: create, clone, destroy, sso_staging, deploy, deploy_files,
                                         deploy_db, deploy_files_db, save_state, restore_state, sso_production',
        ),
        array(
            'cmd'       => 'module',
            'class'     => 'EIG_WP_CLI_Module',
            'shortdesc' => 'Control hosting plugin modules.',
            'longdesc'  => 'Enable, disable and check status of internal modules in the hosting plugin.\n
                           Subcommands: enable, disable, status, list, reset',
        ),
    );
```